# How to create Checkboxes with CheckAll checkbox in react hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

for some reason the program is crash every time there is a value in the devicesKeys array: "Checkbox defines an invalid contextType" and also "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined"

note: In my tests I made sure that "devicesKeys" array is **never** in an undefined state.
it seems like a react context problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

**this is the code:**
https://codesandbox.io/s/youthful-tharp-bmdw4?file=/src/App.js

The original Docs: https://ant.design/components/checkbox/#components-checkbox-demo-check-all

Comment: would you upload your code to sandbox.io or codepen or to anything similar so that it's easy for us to see the problem

Comment: Done. and thanks a lot for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why would you want to use `CheckBoxGroup`, you can achieve it by using `rowSelection` property on table:

```
return (
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      dataSource={devices}
      rowSelection={{ onSelectAll: onCheckAllChange }}
      pagination={false}
    ></Table>
);
```

and callback would be:

```
function onCheckAllChange(selected, selectedRows, changeRows) {
    setCheckState({
      checkedList: selected ? devicesKeys : [],
      indeterminate: false,
      checkAll: selected
    });
}
```

Check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-rhodes-vowfq?file=/mytable.js) out.

## Edit

The suggested method works, but it's deprecated so the suggested method is using the "onChange" callback.

**this is the table:**

```
<Table
  columns={columns}
  dataSource={devices}
  rowSelection={{ onChange }}
  pagination={false}
/>
```

**The callback:**

```
function onChange(checkedList, selectedRows) {
  setCheckedList(checkedList);
}
```

this is a minimal sandbox of the new version:
https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-butterfly-9c52v?file=/mytable.js

Comment: amazing. I was awake all night trying to figure it out. now all works. many thanks.

Comment: Haven't we all have been there! :)